# React: Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-router-dom' in '/usr/src/app/src'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm running a REST API in a docker container. I'm working on building the pages and when I start the server I get:

```
Starting the development server...

Failed to compile.

./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-router-dom' in '/usr/src/app/src'
```

When I refresh the browser, I see the following error `Error: Cannot find module 'react-router-dom'`
I've tried every npm install I could find, because it seemed to be everyone's problem:

```
npm install -S react-router-dom
npm install react-router-dom --save
npm i react-router-dom --save
```

In package.json, I see the dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

My app.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Home } from './Home';
import { Developers } from './Developers';
import { Pricing } from './Pricing';
import { Login } from './Login';
import { NoMatch } from './NoMatch';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path = "/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/developers" component = {Developers} />
            <Route path="/pricing" component = {Pricing} />
            <Route path="/login" component = {Login} />
            <Route component={NoMatch} /> 
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

My index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: is the react app also inside the docker container?

Comment: Yes, its running in the docker container also.

Answer (score 2):

You missed probably:

```
  import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

**AND** because using Docker **drop your images** and recreate them. This solves the problem.
If not do the following:

- Run npm install react-router-dom (or yarn add react-router-dom if you're using Yarn).
- Then check that the import is referencing the package name, not the path (i.e., it should be require('react-router-dom'), not require('./react-router-dom'))
- index.js supposed to be like this

  ```
  import React from 'react';
  import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
  import './index.css';
  import App from './App';
  import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
  import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

  ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById('root'));
  serviceWorker.unregister();
  ```
- restart dev-server
- check if you did `npm i react react-dom react-router-dom`

Please give feedback (comment) what solved your problem and mark this answer then as accepted

Comment: Before drop the images and recreate them, I added `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';` to my index file. I still get the error. I'll try dropping the images.

Comment: Yes with docker you have to drop to get changes working

Comment: I have the same issue, this did not fix it for me. I have dropped all images (including the backend) and re-composed everything several and it still breaks on the dependency every time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try reinstall npm because sometime npm version doeant meet libraries requirement

Answer (score 0):

Since this is running in Docker.

I had to the command `make install dev`

and this seems to fix everything

Comment: I am having the exact same issue but i'm not able to run make command. Any help would be much appreciated.